# custom tab completion with whitespaces

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to write a custom completion function for filenames and sometimes they can have whitespaces.

So far I've been using this

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,MyComplete MyFunc execute MyFunc(<f-args>)
```

But it only completes the last word even with `nargs=1`.

Is there any way to complete arguments containing white spaces?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but I think this is related: [Filename Completion with Spaces](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10539/1841)